# GridView - Itens se repetindo de forma aleatória

Tags: android, gridview, android-adapter

Estou com um problema no grid view. Este grid contém n produtos que são exibidos na tela, assim, o grid de alguns usuários possuem scroll.

Quando não há scroll os produtos são exibidos normalmente, entretanto quando há começam a se repetir em forma aleatória. Pelo que pesquisei isto acontece pela view se reciclar.

O grid view é inflado pelo xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_TextNome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="true">
</TextView>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_ticket_primary600_48dp" >
  </ImageView>
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/item_textPreco"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingTop="5dp"
      android:textSize="19sp"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:textAlignment="center">
  </TextView>
</FrameLayout>
```

E o getview do BaseAdapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = new View(context);

        // get layout from row_grid.xml
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid, null);

        // set value into textview
        TextView nomeProduto = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.item_TextNome);
        TextView precoProduto = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.item_textPreco);


        Produto produto = produtos.get(position);
        nomeProduto.setText(produto.getNome());
        precoProduto.setText("R$" + String.format("%.2f",produto.getPreco()).replace(".",","));

        //Bold
        nomeProduto.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        // set image based on selected text
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
        String mobile = categorias.get(position);

        if (mobile.equals("Bebida")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_beer_primary600_48dp);
        } else if (mobile.equals("Doce")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cupcake_icon_primary_614x460);
        } else if (mobile.equals("Comida")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_restaurant_menu_black_48dp);
        } else if (mobile.equals("Lanche")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_hamburguer_primary600_48dp);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_ticket_primary600_48dp);
        }

    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, você tem razão. Isso acontece porque as views(layout da linha) são reaproveitadas.

O problema no seu código é que está apenas a atribuir os valores às views quando o layout é nulo(`if (convertView == null)`).

Altere o método `getView()` de forma a que sejam atribuidos valores às views quer `convertView` seja nulo ou não:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        //gridView = new View(context);

        // get layout from row_grid.xml
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid, null);

        // set value into textview
        TextView nomeProduto = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_TextNome);
        TextView precoProduto = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_textPreco);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);


    } 
    Produto produto = produtos.get(position);
    nomeProduto.setText(produto.getNome());
    precoProduto.setText("R$" + String.format("%.2f",produto.getPreco()).replace(".",","));

    //Bold
    nomeProduto.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

    // set image based on selected text

    String mobile = categorias.get(position);

    if (mobile.equals("Bebida")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_beer_primary600_48dp);
    } else if (mobile.equals("Doce")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cupcake_icon_primary_614x460);
    } else if (mobile.equals("Comida")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_restaurant_menu_black_48dp);
    } else if (mobile.equals("Lanche")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_hamburguer_primary600_48dp);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_ticket_primary600_48dp);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Nota: Não precisa de usar uma nova variável(`View gridView;`) use `convertView`.

Comment: Realmente! Todas considerações foram muito válidas! Obrigado pela contribuição